# vim change backslash key for hotkeys

Tags: vim

Recently I acquaint myself with vim editor and its hotkey system, however I am not confident that I am ok with the first character in its system, I want to try another one as the first hotkey.
How can I change the first key in a hotkey sequences from backslash to another in vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
:let mapleader = ","
```

In an interactive session. To make it permanent, add it to your `.vimrc` without the `:`.

I'd recommend to read `:help leader`.

Comment: quote "Note that the value of "mapleader" is used at the moment the mapping is defined.  Changing "mapleader" after that has no effect for already defined mappings" How to change the current mapping?

Comment: Well, you can't. At least, you can dump your mapped keys with `:map`, but sadly not into a buffer/register. But, if you are capable (AND using Linux and a terminal and a mouse, just copy the dumped output with the mouse, open up another buffer, past it, make some changes, then source the buffer. It can be done...

Comment: "open up another buffer, past it, make some changes, then source the buffer" - I don't understand the end, but mb you mean change some configuration files where this hotkeys are set and set another value to them or what? For example, I have c++ plugin where there are a lot of  hotkeys and commands how I can change the map leader for this plugin forever.

Comment: It depends on how they are defined in your plugin. If it's like `map <leader>SOME_OTHER_KEY <FUNCTIONALITY>`, if you set it up in your `.vimrc` like in my answer, it will use `,` as the leader key.

Comment: Don't forget `noremap \ ,` if you also want to have comma's original behavior of jumping to the next `f` or `t` occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

As Zsolt said, the common way to do this is to change ***mapleader*** and **maplocalleader**, the first one being more often used.

However, this works in a way that Vim simply takes the *value* of ***mapleader*** and substitutes it when sourcing Vim scripts. Therefore, after starting Vim changing ***mapleader*** does nothing, unless you're sourcing some additional files.

So, either take

```
let mapleader  = "some-other-key"
```

and put it in your .vimrc

or re-source all the files in your $VIM and $VIMFILES hierarchy. The first way being *more safe*. Vim is designes to be quick to start and restart, after all.

If you provide specific examples of what plugins you're having trouble with, then maybe we can help more on that. But on what is given ...